# Логирование(NLog) после публикации приложения ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, логирование, asp.net-web-api, nlog

Есть ASP.NET приложение, в котором используется NLog, после публикации приложения не работает логирование. dll на месте, конфиги тоже, в остальном приложение функционирует полноценно. Может кто подскажет в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После публикации приложение работает либо от того пользователя под кем прошла имперсонация (IIS_IUSRS если не прошла), либо (реже) от учетки пула приложений (по умолчанию IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool).

Этим пользователям нужно дать права на запись в папку с логами.

Comment: Спасибо! В точку!